# I can't display elements with Appium Inspector

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios, appium-java, mobile-emulator

I'm testing an iOS app,
I'm using this capabilitys on my Appium Inspector

```
{
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 14",
  "appium:platformName": "ios",
  "appium:platformVersion": "16.2",
  "appium:bundleId": "********",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
  "appium:settings[snapshotMaxDepth]": 70,
  "appium:settings[customSnapshotTimeout]": "50000"
}
```

I'm using Appium 2

Appium Inspector still loading and I don't the app source

I want to get xpath element with Appium inspector

Any help please